# Update on peer-to-peer lending sites - buyback guarantee and secondary market

Tags: peer-to-peer-lending, maturity, asset-protection

I read several questions about peer-to-peer lending that were asked something like 5 years ago. 
I just started investing in two sites (A and B from Riga, Latvia). Apparently p2p investing today 2015/16 has changed a bit. Moreover it is interestint to see that Baltic countries (Estonia, Latvia) enter the market (for example by subsidiaries of Scandinavian banks):

- A offers protected loans. Meaning that if loans are overdue for (approx) 30 days they repay the loan and interest to the lender.
- maturities are relatively short, starting with 1 month at A but also B has shorter and longer terms.
- B has a lot of loans in the secondary market where loans are sold at par or premium mostly and sometimes with discount.

So my questions are:

- How can a p2p site offer protection in the above sense? Do they put the loan back to the originator?
- Having read other questions here I see that the liquidity was an issue 5 years back. These days with horizons of only a couple of months this seems not to be a problem anymore. What do you think about this development?
- These days I only see loans in the secondary market at premium or with the same YTM as freshly issued loans. Given the fact that the site takes a 1% charge for secondary market trades - does it make any sense to invest there?

I hope this question serves as an update on the topic.

Comment: Is this an advertisement?

Comment: no, it is not .. I just saw the other questions. They all mentioned the sites, the interest rate and other specific information. So I thought it is ok to include them here too.

Comment: Reading the questions from 5 years back p2p seemed to be not that great (some had good experiences, some not), and I just discovered it last week ... and it looks fine to me after 5 days ... so I thought about discussing here. If you check out my profile then you see tha I am active on other exchange sites as well.

Comment: Rule of thumb: if something looks too good to be true - it is likely too good to be true.

Comment: Yes .. but maybe 13% interest is not too good to be true .. especially if they do not mean rate-of-return which is lower ... maybe the concept has improved. It is just funny that those company seem to be located in the Baltic states mainly.

Comment: 13% might sound great, but even if your loan is protected and insured to death so you can't lose it, ever.... If the rate is so high because the underlying risk is high, protection may not help your net long term ROI. If you make 10 loans at that rate and 9 default, then over all you will make a tiny return, because you achieved 0% on 9 of them, and 13% on one.

Comment: @Michael 1) I edited out the names 2) I am aware of credit portfolio mathemtics. I just think that for short term consumer loans 13% is not too unrealistic. What if the shop gives the shopper a loan at a very low rate and pays the rest by itself to increase sales - reducing its profit a bit? 5 years ago I read about mich higher rates at the sites mentioned then.

Comment: @Richard A sustained and reliable 13% is a very good ROI by most peoples standards, especially in the current climate of reducing ROIs. I have to say I think littleadv is justified in quoting "if it looks too good to be true then it probably is". To be a viable investment vehicle you need to achieve 13% long term, and generally market forces would see to it that the return reduces, or maybe after doing 100 short term loans at 13% 20 at a time, 15% of which failed (0%), you'd suddenly find you lost 30 all at once because of economic environmental changes... Your over all ROI would then be 8.5%.

Comment: We don't know you're not on to a good thing of course, but you need to look at it really carefully. Maybe if all the p2p loans started failing at once the p2p company would fail and your losses on the last 20 loans would be -100% instead of 0%. The point is, there is never a magic bullet because if there was everyone would be riding it. If they are really saying you can be 13% then I'd suggest that there must be risk attached. At best the risk is that your gain is limited to 0% (and that could happen whilst they cream profit out of your capital still) but it could also include losing your cap.

Comment: Your profile says you're in Vienna - is it the Austrian / EU p2p market you're interested in? Questions like this really need a country tag as legalities and base interest rates vary so much.

Comment: Right, I am from Austria, Europe. I edit the question, Michael told me to delete the names of the respective sites ... they are in Latvia.

Answer (score 2):

All lenders make money from loans, despite the fact that there will be some defaults, they just have to make enough money from those that don't default to offset the losses from those that do, so that their over all profit is good enough to be justified, so there's no reason the p2p lending companies can't protect your loan. If you remove the risk of losing your investment you can expect your return to be reduced though, as they have to take more profit away from you in order to fund the pool used to pay out when there is a default. This doesn't necessarily mean your money is completely safe though, if the p2p lender itself went bust you would probably still lose your money, unless it was appropriately insured.

I'm not sure liquidity is really the right word really, liquidity is about encashment without serious penalty. If you can transfer the debt to someone else at any time then liquidity is good, but if you don't really have that option (as most lenders don't) then your investment amount (whatever isn't paid back yet) is completely illiquid still, just for a shorter time. I don't see how the term is important myself, there are many investments that have differing maturity time scales, and you just have to pick one that has a suitable time scale, return and risk for you.

1% charge or not, there is still an ultimate net return on investment, secondary market or not. Virtually any investment has costs of some sort, you just have to take them into account and make sure you don't get fooled into thinking the ROI is better than it seems because of the way they've packaged and presented it.

Comment: "*encashment"* what a great word...